# How to retrieve json object elements that are not in an array?

Tags: android, json, listview

I have this json data below, but I am wondering how I can retrieve the  pair of symbol and figure and display it in a Listview.I am only able to retrieve the elements if they are in a JSON Array.Please Help

```
{ "rates": {
    "AED": 3.672626,
    "AFN": 48.3775,
    "ALL": 110.223333,
    "AMD": 409.604993,
     "ZAR": 8.416205,
    "ZMK": 4954.411262,
    "ZWL": 322.355011
}
```

}

Comment: Please, I know what json is but I cannot understand your question.  Please use paragraph and question mark.  Could you possibly explain what you are aiming at?  Could you be a little more clear?

Answer (score 0):

```
JSONObject jsonResult = new JSONObject(yourString);
JSONObject rates = jsonResult.getJSONObject("rates");
double aed = rates.getDouble("AED");
double afn = rates.getDouble("AFN");
....
```

Comment: Thanks this is helpful, but I still have one problem.Is it possible to  get all the elements without specifying the symbol(e.g "AED") and displaying them in a pair?

Answer (score 0):

try as:

```
JSONObject jarrau = new JSONObject("Your JSON String");

    JSONObject jsonobj = jarrau.getJSONObject("rates");
    double dub_AED,dub_AFN, dub_ALL;
     //AAED
    if(!jsonobj.isNull("AED"))
     dub_AED=jsonobj.getDouble("AED");
    else
       // set default value here
     //AFN
    if(!jsonobj.isNull("AFN"))
     dub_AFN=jsonobj.getDouble("AFN");
    else
       // set default value here        
     //ALL
    if(!jsonobj.isNull("ALL"))
     dub_ALL=jsonobj.getDouble("ALL");
    else
       // set default value here

    // pasre all same as...
```

Answer (score 0):

As you don't no the keys here in this case we also need to get the keys from the json so in that case we need first keys then we need to get the value of that particular key.

So for that the following is the code :-

```
    String[] sKey,sValue;

    JSONObject jobject = new JSONObject(your result);
    JSONObject jobj = jobject;

    JSONObject jrates = jobj.getJSONObject("rates");

    sKey = new String[jrates.length()];
    sValue = new String[jrates.length()];

    for(int i=0;i<jrates.length();i++){
    sKey[i] = (String)keys.next();
    sValue[i] = (String)jrates.getString(sKey[i]);
    }
```